# Server Sent Events with CORS support

Tags: c#, servicestack, cors, server-sent-events

I am using [Server Sent Events in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) and I need to allow its use across origins.

I have setup the ServiceStack `CorsFeature` in my application, but this is not honoured by the `ServerEventsFeature`.

I can manually add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the `OnCreated`, and that allows requests to `event-stream`, but requests to the heartbeat fail, because I cannot set a header on this request.

```cs
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    HeartbeatInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,30),
    OnCreated = (subscription, request) => {
        request.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    }
    ...
}
```

As the SSE functionality [is implemented on a RawHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L61), I can't see how to get this header into the request. Is there a way I can set the header for all `/event-` url's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `/event-stream` and `/event-heartbeat` are Raw HTTP Handlers, the other `event-*` routes are normal ServiceStack services which go through ServiceStack's Request Pipeline.

I've added a change to automatically apply `Config.GlobalResponseHeaders` to both `/event-stream` and `/event-heartbeat` handlers [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7563855c64c1cfec1cdd05fd6fcfa73600ae7190). This change should now automatically add the [CORS Headers when CorsFeature is enabled](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/04e88413821c8fbe1cf57fdc4a5026069fb565b8/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs#L66).

I've also added `OnHeartbeatInit` for `/event-heartbeat` callback to match `/event-stream` `OnInit` callback so you can also add custom headers to the Heartbeat handler as well.

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    HeartbeatInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,30),
    OnInit = (request) => {
        request.Response.AddHeader(...);
    },
    OnHeartbeatInit = (request) => {
        request.Response.AddHeader(...);
    },
    ...
}
```

This change is available from **v4.0.34+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks Demis :) This may be my new favourite feature of ServiceStack.

Comment: @Scott ahh cool, glad to hear it :) hope you do something fun with it!

Comment: It's going inside an Enterprise iPad application instead of Apple Push notifications. That's fun for me :/

Comment: @mythz I am using SSE and having trouble with CORS.  I am using the newish allowOriginWhitelist in CorsFeature, can you double check that PreRequestFilters are being applied to SSE requests?  Works on my local machine but not a remote one.